# Seleccionar registro MYSQL segun expresion regular (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema al buscar un id dentro de un "arreglo" en mi base de datos:

**esta es mi tabla platos:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla insumos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla platos dentro del campo insumos almaceno el id y la cantidad que contiene cada plato con el siguiente formato `ID_INSUMO:CANTIDAD_DE_INSUMOS;ID_INSUMO:CANTIDAD_DE_INSUMOS;ID_INSUMO:CANTIDAD_DE_INSUMOS;`
por ejemplo si el plato contiene 2 insumo-prueba(id:10) se pone 10:2

Lo que no puedo es con un select buscar todos los platos que contengan el id:10 como insumo

Intente lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM `platos` WHERE `insumos` REGEXP '(10):[0-9]{0,}'
```

me muestra todos los resultados que contengan 10:[0-9] incluyendo tambien 110:[0-9] 1111110:[0-9] y lo unico que deseo extraer es 10:[0-9] que empieze con 10: y termine en un numero

De antemano gracias.

NOTA: si es que en vez de usar regexp usamos like o alguna opcion mas "ligera" me ayudaria bastante

Comment: Si en una base de datos **relacional** se tratan de evitar las **relaciones**, tienes un problema, sobre todo en casos tan evidentes como éste. Te harías una gran favor si *normalizas* esa tabla; el no hacerlo va a implicar un costo. La opción con SQL no será ligera, o no será con SQL.

Answer (score 0):

La primera recomendación sería: intente cambiar el diseño de su tabla: `platos`, principalmente la columna: `insumos`, extraer información de esa columna, como puede observar es algo complicado. Quizás una opción sería crear una nueva tabla: `plato-insumos`.

Sin embargo, posiblemente no pueda cambiar el diseño de su tabla por distintos motivos, así que puede usar algo como:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `platos`
WHERE `insumos` REGEXP '(^10|\;10)\:';
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=192289b39fe7562c052cdeaf62807ea8).

Answer (score 0):

Una opción para obtener todos los platos que contengan el insumo con ID 10 utilizando `LIKE` es:

```
SELECT *
FROM platos
WHERE CONCAT(';', insumos) LIKE '%;10:%';
```

Sabemos que después del ID del insumo está el caracter ":" y antes del ID en todos los casos (excepto el primer ID) está el caracter ";", por lo que concateno el caracter ";" al inicio de la columna insumos en cada fila para realizar la búsqueda. Si hubiera espacios entre el ID y los caracteres ";" y ":" esta opción no funcionaria (todas las filas deben respetar el mismo formato).

No estoy seguro que el rendimiento sea mejor que utilizar expresiones regulares.

Coincido con @wchiquito de que la mejor opción sería utilizar una tabla plato-insumos. Otra opción es que insumos en la tabla platos sea del tipo `JSON`, lo que facilitaría las búsquedas.